# How do I search for a word in a string which is in an array with different combinations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an an array something like:

```
["Rob Meyer", "Michelle Preston"]
```

I want to search for an occurrence of `rob or Rob, or meyer or Meyer` and so on, any "word" in the array, no characters but just words and not case sensitive.

So how do I do that? `include?` looks for an exact match. I am looking for something that is more flexible here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
query = 'rob'
["Rob Meyer", "Michelle Preston"].any?{|e| e =~ /\b#{query}\b/i}
```

Comment: This will return true when the array is `["robber"]` and the search string is `"Rob"`.

Comment: Now it works as long as the delimiter is a space, but is fragile, and is ugly. There is a better regex to do that.

Comment: is there a way i could use `params[:type]` in there?

Comment: @sawa: yes there is. using the boundary matcher \b now.

Comment: @psharma: you can use variable interpolation inside regexps, updated the answer to do that

Answer (score 1):

Precompile the list of words.

```
words = ["Rob Meyer", "Michelle Preston"].flat_map{|s| s.downcase.scan(/\w+/)}

words.include?("Rob".downcase) # => true
```

Comment: This is nice! You could make it even simpler by moving the downcase into the first map: ["Rob Meyer", "Michelle Preston"]
.flat_map{|s| s.downcase.scan(/\w+/)}

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are looking for a match operation. Ruby allows you to use regular expressions (regex).

Read up on the **match()** method, and I'm sure you'll find what you need.

When using a regex in Ruby, following the expression with "/i" will make it case-insensitive.

I usually go to http://ruby-doc.org/ to find Ruby language specifics.

Good luck!

Comment: `match` is an overkill and is slower than `=~` when you just want a boolean value.

Comment: match and =~ are the same method as far as I can tell https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L8622

Comment: They are not. `=~` returns the position when there is a match, and `match` returns a `MatchData`.

Comment: Oops, misread the c slightly. I don't see from the code why it would be any slower though - they both do the same work, it's just storing the results in the magic globals versus a match data instance

Answer (score 0):

I do this sort of thing often:

```
names = ["Rob Meyer", "Michelle Preston"]

targets = %w[rob meyer]
regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(targets).source })\b/i
# => /\b(?:rob|meyer)\b/i

names.select{ |name| name[regex] }
```

Which returns an array of the names that hit:

```
[
    [0] "Rob Meyer"
]
```

The reason I use `Regexp.union` is it's trivial to take a huge list of possible targets, instantly create a pattern to search for them, then search many megabytes of text for hits, all running at the speed of the regex engine, without iterations. It's about as fast as we can search in Ruby.

`name[regex]` is the basis for generating a true/false value. Changing it to `!!name[regex]` will return a boolean true/false value.

Instead of embedding it in a `select` which grabs the names with a hit, it could be done inside a loop with a conditional:

```
names.each do |name|
  if name[regex]
    puts "got a hit for '#{ name }'"
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
got a hit for 'Rob Meyer'
```